# Set require view based on views

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

So I need some field required for specific participant in the middle of the workflow.

The 1st few participant won't even see that field in their view.

If I set the field mandatory, then there will be error even for those views without that view.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.